# How to get the active tab url in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, electron

I am looking for a solution to get the url from the active tab of the browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari etc) for a cross platform desktop app made in Electron js.

I found a solution for mac to get the active tab url's of "Chrome" and "Safari" using "applescript" but still could not find a way for "Firefox".

Is there any smart way to get the url of the active tab of the browser in Mac, Windows and Linux using Node js?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a tab's url in a browser, from a separate electron (chromium) app?

Comment: FYI, it's not even entirely obvious what browser the user is using?  It could be numerous different browsers.  There could even be more than one running at once.  There could be multiple windows open, each with their own active tab.

Comment: @Samathingamajig , yes I am looking for the currently active tab's url of a browser, from a separate electron (chromium) app.

Comment: @jfriend00 , I am looking for browser specific code. That means if the browser is chrome then the url of the active tab of chrome.

Answer (score 2):

For firefox in linux you will find the file ->
`~/.mozilla/firefox/iq8hatig.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4`

To parse this file in nodejs you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookmark-parser

```
    BMParser.readFromJSONLZ4File("~/.mozilla/firefox/iq8hatig.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4")
        .then(result => { 
          console.log(result.windows)
       }).catch(err => {
         res.send(err);
       });
```

last entry in this file is the active tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this one for firefox. Do you know any way for the other browsers??

Comment: In linux for chrome: `~/'.config/google-chrome/Default/Current Session'`

Comment: Thank you very much. Does windows have similar file in the chrome folder in the installed directory?

Answer (score -4):

Here is the code you can find browser URL

```
let url = window.location.href
```

Comment: I am not looking for that. I want to detect the open url of another browser from the desktop app.